# Haxe/php Array.length

Tags: php, arrays, haxe

I have a problem with the translation of a for-loop from Haxe to php. The loop traces the content of my array "steps". In Haxe it is working fine.

Haxe Code:

```
private var _steps:Array<Step> = new Array<Step>();

public function initFrontendData(steps:Array<Step>) {
    _steps = steps;     

    for (i in 0..._steps.length) {
        var step:Step = _steps[i];
        trace("Step: "+ step.id + ", Name: " + step.name + "<br />");
    }
}
```

But if I use the translates php code I get the error:
uncaught exception: Trying to get property of non-object (errno: 8) in path\konf\Konfigurator.class.php at line #28Trying to get property of non-object.

Line 28 is $_g = $this->_steps->length;

Generated php code:

```
public $_steps;
public function initFrontendData($steps) {
    $this->_steps = $steps;
    {
        $_g1 = 0;
        $_g = $this->_steps->length;
        while($_g1 < $_g) {
            $i = $_g1++;
            $step = $this->_steps[$i];
            haxe_Log::trace("Schritt " . _hx_string_rec($step->id, "") . ", " . _hx_string_or_null($step->name) . "<br />", _hx_anonymous(array("fileName" => "Konfigurator.hx", "lineNumber" => 76, "className" => "konf.Konfigurator", "methodName" => "initFrontendData")));
            unset($step,$i);
        }
    }       
}
```

If I manually change the line 28 from:

```
$_g = $this->_steps->length;
```

to

```
$_g = count($this->_steps);
```

everything works fine. But I don't want to change the generated php code manually and I think its not the intention of Haxe to change generated code manually.

Do I have an error in my Haxe code or has the php translator of Haxe a Bug? How can I solve the problem without changing the generated php code?

thx Pockie

Comment: Well what type is $steps? If its an array (as i expect) then the php code needs ammending.

Comment: Yes $steps is an array. Like I mentioned I don't want to change the generated php code manually. I have to write my project in Haxe and then Haxe compiles the code to php. But the generated php code is defected. I know where to find and solve the error in php. But I don't find the error in Haxe and why Haxe generates defective php code.

Comment: Are you sure your source array is an Haxe generated array and not a native PHP array? If it is a native one, it needs to be wrapped using php.Lib.toHaxeArray(native)

see http://api.haxe.org/php/Lib.html#toHaxeArray

Comment: Thank you Franco. You solved my problem. My array was  native php and no Haxe array.

Comment: Either you or Franco(btw, hi Franco!) should answer the question and you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Franco Ponticelli answered the question in the comments section of my question.

Quote:
Are you sure your source array is an Haxe generated array and not a native PHP array? If it is a native one, it needs to be wrapped using php.Lib.toHaxeArray(native) see api.haxe.org/php/Lib.html#toHaxeArray –  Franco Ponticelli 2 days ago